# How to batch data using circular buffer

Tags: java, circular-buffer

I have created a circular buffer and would like to create a batch of 1000 records.Once my buffer is 1000 records I would liek to write the data to a file and clear the buffer. Every batch is going to be a new file. I tried using the reset() method to reset the buffer after the capacity is full. I am clueless how to write the data as a new file.Please help

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class DataBuffer<T> {

    public T[] elements = null;

    public int capacity = 0;
    public int writePos = 0;
    public int readPos = 0;

    public boolean flipMarker = false;

    public DataBuffer(Class<T> type, int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final T[] elements = (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, capacity);
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public T get(int i) {
        return elements[i];
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.writePos = 0;
        this.readPos = 0;
        this.flipMarker = false;
    }

    public int available() {
        if (!flipMarker) {
            return capacity - writePos;
        }
        return readPos - writePos;
    }

    public int remainingCapacity() {
        if (!flipMarker) {
            return capacity - writePos;
        }
        return readPos - writePos;
    }

    public boolean put(T element) {
        if (!flipMarker) {
            if (writePos == capacity) {
                writePos = 0;
                flipMarker = true;

                if (writePos < readPos) {
                    elements[writePos++] = element;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                elements[writePos++] = element;
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (writePos < readPos) {
                elements[writePos++] = element;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public T take() {
        if (!flipMarker) {
            if (readPos < writePos) {
                return elements[readPos++];
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            if (readPos == capacity) {
                readPos = 0;
                flipMarker = false;

                if (readPos < writePos) {
                    return elements[readPos++];
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                return elements[readPos++];
            }
        }
    }

    public List<T> getAll(){
        return (List<T>) Arrays.asList(elements);
    }
}
```

The code which tried to spill the data to disk is as below

```
private DataBuffer<Employee> processedSyslogDataBuffer = new DataBuffer<>(Employee.class, 1000);
 processedSyslogDataBuffer.put(processedMessage);
if(processedSyslogDataBuffer.remainingCapacity() == 0) {
    List<Employee> data = processedSyslogDataBuffer.getAll();
    logger.info("Writing processed data with size :: "+data.size());
    writerService.writeProcessed(data);
   logger.info("resetting the buffer to accomodate next batch of records");
    processedSyslogDataBuffer.reset();
}
```

Comment: Your code is not thread-safe can it be source of your problem?

Comment: In my case for every thread I am creating a new object within the thread context

Comment: I don't understand why you use `processedSyslogDataBuffer` at all. You put message and then immediately get it back.

Comment: Actually I wanted to batch data of 1000 records. Clueless of how to implement I came to SO. Could you please help. The goal is to create batches of data and spill them to disk as small files.

Comment: Did you tried to ask this question on SO? :) because this one is not even close to what you need.

Comment: The problem is that your buffer is circular, but a file is not. You have to decide what you want your file to contain. What happens to the file when data is taken off the buffer? is it also moved out of the file? Is the buffer a sliding window into the file? I'd say your question is way too broad.

Comment: Every batch is going to be a new file

Comment: @talex I will edit the question